# Configure actuator endpoints security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

The Spring Boot Actuator Endpoints are by default protected by basic http security.

Can this be changed to use Spring Security?
I've setup Spring Security successfully and use this to protect my other pages.

I tried `security.basic.enabled: false` and adding `.antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")` in my authorize requests (note I'm using a different url as root for the endpoints) but this didn't help.
I keep getting a basic http auth log, which does not users configured in the AuthenticationManager.

Any idea?

**EDIT - providing more details -**

My Application.java looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/app").setViewName("app/index");
        registry.addViewController("/app/login").setViewName("app/login");
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
    }

    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 8)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test1")
                    .password("test1pw")
                    .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .withUser("test2")
                    .password("test2pw")
                    .roles("USER");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/app/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/app/login")
                    .failureUrl("/app/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/app")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/app/login?logout");
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            web
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/assets/**");
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

In my `application.yml` I also have:

```
management:
  context-path: /management
```

Note that is setup is the same as you the guide you mentioned.

Now what I would expect - or like to configure - is that the /manage endpoints like health, mappings etc would be protected with users from the customized AuthenticationManager.

I also tried to add `management.security.enabled=false`and this indeed switches off authentication for e.g. /manage/mappings.
The problematic thing however is that I explicitly told Spring Security to protect these urls's via:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

but this does not work. Note other authorize matchers do work.
I wonder if has something to do within timing/order. I copied `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 8)` from the sample but I don't know why - 8 is used.

To delve a little bit deeper I've also run the sample (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security) myself and I see the same behaviour in the sample application.
The management security is seems completely independent of the `user` and `admin` users configured in the sample's in memory authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this be changed to use Spring Security?

It **is** Spring Security (what else did you think we'd use?). If you just want to keep the default security rules and customize the `AuthenticationManager` it should just work if you use the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` as recommended by the Spring Security team. The [secure method sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security) has the behavior you are looking for, so you can copy the configuration pattern from there. The key thing, if you want to replace the Boot default authentication strategy, is to get the `AuthenticationManager` configured in a `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` [like in the sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0aa93036fa34eee08efcff90af3711a69577ef05/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security/src/main/java/sample/ui/method/SampleMethodSecurityApplication.java#L77).

You can switch off management security with `management.security.enabled=false` (assuming Spring Security is on the classpath). It is mentioned in the [user guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-security), but feel free to propose clarifications.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. I see same behaviour btw in the sample you mentioned (on which my code is based).

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave my answer as it is for now, because that's the expected behaviour, but it looks like that's not what happens. I added some test cases to the sample to see if they can help us to explain ([github issue here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/699)).

Comment: I updated the answer with pointers to the new, correct code in the sample.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to respond again. The updated security sample using GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter does indeed work. However there is one strange thing going on: when I disable management security via management.security.enabled=false but instead set up a custom spring security antMatcher [e.g. .antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole("ADMIN")] then the management urls like /management/mappings are unsecured. It seems management.security.enabled=false completely overrules other spring security settings.

Comment: and btw was is the difference between init() and configure() methods in GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: I suspect pilot error in the custom ant matcher case, but you'll have to share a complete project for me to know for sure. The init and config methods are a bit of a black art to me as well, I must admit, but you could check the Spring Security docs for help.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've setup a simple sample project at https://github.com/marceloverdijk/boot-actuator-security. The README.md contains more info how to reproduce. Imo this can be a quite  important security vulnerability. If you need any other info let me know.

Comment: OK, that's actually the intended behaviour, if you set management.security.enabled=false. You can see that from `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (it adds all the endpoints to the ignored list if that flag is "false"). Makes sense to me.

Comment: OK that explains it Dave. But can I can use my custom login page to protect the management endpoints?

Comment: Yes. Just unset that flag (and make sure your filter has a high enough precedence, or low enough `Order`).

Comment: Yes when I use `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 11)` instead of `-8` then it works. It feels a little bit of magic to pick a value as using `-10` even stops starting up because the @Order is not unqiue

Comment: I don't think there's much we can do about that - it's how Spring Security works. Maybe we could provide some static fields with suggested order values for some common use cases?

Comment: Yes I understand. I was also thinking about Boot using constants itself so apps can use them and do -/+ 1. But providing constants for common cases would be even better.

Comment: Setting `management.security.enabled=false` does not work if other management port is used.

Comment: `management.security.enabled` was removed in spring security 6

Answer (score 1):

I would say that sometimes it's easier to exclude autoconfiguration of Spring Boot component and make configuration from scratch if you have very specific case. In this case you could use:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Or just `ManagementWebSecurityConfiguration.java` if you want to keep the rest of Boot Security configuration. And then you could use something like that:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSecurity(SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configuration
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private SecurityProperties security;

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationSecurity(SecurityProperties security) {
        this.security = security;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // you configuration
    }


}

}
```

As you can see I have reused the SecurityProperties in this case in order to avoid make my own.